# Does placing the most likely-matched function heads first offer any benefit?

Tags: erlang, elixir

Say we have several `function heads` or `case do` patterns to match on.

Will placing *"common case"* or *"most likely"* headers first offer any benefits?

I'm seeing timing improvements when I re-order `case do` match patterns in ELIXIR, putting the most common pattern first.

I had expected the VM to optimize this away, and the order shouldn't matter.

Example:

```
  for {s, i} <- li do
    case :binary.split(s, spliter, [:global]) do
      [_, tag, val, _, _] -> 
        # this pattern occurs over 9/10 times.
        # in files with over 100000 rows matching this pattern
        # reduced processing time
        {:tv, i, tag, val}

      [_, "data", _] ->
        Process.put(:data_tag, true)
        {:tb, i, "data"}

      [_, "/data", _] ->
        Process.put(:data_tag, false)
        {:te, i, "data"}

      [_, "/" <> tag, _] ->
        if Process.get(:data_tag) do
          {nil, i}
        else
          {:te, i, tag}
        end

      [_, "?xml" <> _, _] ->
        {nil, i}

      [_, "!--" <> _, _] ->
        {nil, i}

      [_, "return" <> _, _] ->
        {nil, i}

      [_, tag, _] ->
        if Process.get(:data_tag) do
          {:tv, i, tag, ""}
        else
          {:tb, i, tag}
        end

      _ ->
        {nil, i}
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There should be no benefit aside from readability. Elixir still compiles down to Erlang abstract syntax trees, and the Erlang compiler allows itself to reorder clauses to be as efficient as it can.

In older versions of the compiler, guard clauses could interfere with this ability and so you'd have an advantage in setting all non-guard clauses nearer the top, but continuous improvements to the Erlang compiler make it less likely that it could optimize.

Still, as you have found, there may be wider branching cases where the compiler won't see a really obvious way to improve run-times (for example, checking multiple literals of the same exact type) and you may see benefits.

Comment: as mentioned above, i don't expect any difference, but was surprised to see an improvement when i re-ordered the case -do pattern checks, putting the most likely cases first. Then again, my measurements could be wrong

Answer (score 3):

You are expecting too much from the Erlang compiler :)

While the answer given here so far is definitely correct and Erlang compiler may reorder the clauses, it cannot predict *what binaries will be more frequent in your input*.

That said, one might expect the optimization of clauses having different guards and/or being mutually exclusive, but the compiler cannot know you receive `"?xml"` more frequently than `"data"`.

Comment: I totally get your point, but my question is still, is the function head lookup and case - do a o(1) operation? or if knowing our expected payload, can we get any benefit from re-ordering the pattern look up appropriately

Comment: > but the compiler cannot know you receive "?xml" more frequently than "data"

This seems to point to possibility of us being able to optimize if we have some knowledge of the expected data

Comment: Sure. There is no _promise_ compiler would optimize anything, and, furthermore, it is very cautious in doing that (because it’s  generally a dangerous destructive operation.) We surely can optimize clauses if we have some knowledge of the expected data.